# CWS InApp purchases and recurring payments

Tags: google-chrome-extension, chrome-web-store

I have published a free extension on the CWS and I want to add  2 subscription types as in-app purchases ( professional and corporate edition ) . I would like to sell these as monthly subscription but as it says on https://developer.chrome.com/webstore/payments-iap#inapp-buy

*Note: Recurring payments are not currently supported through the Chrome Web Store interface.*

Is there a way to upload the SKU details of a InApp subscription at all? What are my options?

Comment: Google Wallet for digital goods supports automated recurring billing. To set up recurring billing, follow the instructions for setting up [subscriptions](https://developers.google.com/wallet/digital/docs/subscriptions) for the Google Wallet for digital goods API.

Comment: @gui47 You just _love_ answering questions in comments, don't you?

Comment: @gui47 No, it seems it isn't. Self-destructing it in a few minutes.

Comment: Thanks but GW4DG is being retired: https://support.google.com/wallet/business/answer/6107573?hl=en

Comment: To clarify further. I want to sell a subscription as an in-app purchase. Reason is that a) I want the  extension to be free ( free trial is not what I want ) b) I want to sell 2 types of subscriptions.

Answer (score 0):

As expected, it is currently not possible to implement multiple tiers of subscriptions using features of the Chrome Webstore. This needs to be implemented using e.g. userapp.io or similar service.